# R Average values of posixct rows by hour

Tags: r, mean, posixct

I have a dataframe 'df1' that has a posixct column 'Date' and other data columns with values associated with dates and times in 'Date'. The date look like this:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-14 13:10:00 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-03-14 13:20:00 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-03-14 13:30:00 | 4 | 6 |
| 2022-03-14 13:40:00 | 5 | 7 |
| 2022-03-14 13:50:00 | 6 | 8 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | 10 | 40 |
| 2022-03-14 14:10:00 | 20 | 50 |
| 2022-03-14 14:20:00 | 30 | 60 |
| 2022-03-14 14:30:00 | 40 | 70 |
| 2022-03-14 14:40:00 | 50 | 80 |
| 2022-03-14 14:50:00 | 60 | 90 |

I would like to average the values in 'Value1' and 'Value2' over all instances of each days hour and create a new dataframe 'df2' where 'Date' is now the start of each hour for each day and 'Value1' is the average values. The resulting df2 would look like:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 13:00:00 | 3.5 | 5.5 |
| 2022-03-14 14:00:00 | 35 | 65 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `floor_date()` from `lubridate` to round the date-time object down to the nearest boundary of hours.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(Date = floor_date(Date, "hour")) %>%
  summarise(across(contains("Value"), mean))

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#   Date                Value1 Value2
#   <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2022-03-14 13:00:00    3.5    5.5
# 2 2022-03-14 14:00:00   35     65
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- read.csv(text = "Date, Value1, Value2
2022-03-14 13:00:00, 1, 3
2022-03-14 13:10:00, 2, 4
2022-03-14 13:20:00, 3, 5
2022-03-14 13:30:00, 4, 6
2022-03-14 13:40:00, 5, 7
2022-03-14 13:50:00, 6, 8
2022-03-14 14:00:00, 10, 40
2022-03-14 14:10:00, 20, 50
2022-03-14 14:20:00, 30, 60
2022-03-14 14:30:00, 40, 70
2022-03-14 14:40:00, 50, 80
2022-03-14 14:50:00, 60, 90", colClasses = c(Date = "POSIXct"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to summarise my all columns so that you don't have to rely on column names?

Comment: @Jacob you can try different "tidy selection" syntax in `across()`. If you want to summarize all columns except the grouping variables, try `across(everything(), mean)`. Another choice can be `across(where(is.numeric), mean)` that summarizes all numeric columns.

Comment: That's a great solution in case all columns don't have a common str in their name. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` if you previously parse your Date to char:

```
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
substr(df$Date, 15,16) <- "00"
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Value1 = mean(Value1), Value2 = mean(Value2))
```

Output:

```
A tibble: 2 × 3
 Date                Value1 Value2
 <dttm>                <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2022-03-14 13:00:00    3.5    5.5
2 2022-03-14 14:00:00   35     65
```

Data:

```
    df <- data.frame(
  Date = as.POSIXct(c("2022-03-14 13:00:00",
           "2022-03-14 13:10:00","2022-03-14 13:20:00","2022-03-14 13:30:00",
           "2022-03-14 13:40:00","2022-03-14 13:50:00","2022-03-14 14:00:00",
           "2022-03-14 14:10:00","2022-03-14 14:20:00","2022-03-14 14:30:00",
           "2022-03-14 14:40:00","2022-03-14 14:50:00")),
  Value1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L),
  Value2 = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L)
)
```

Comment: Theoretically, `Date` should be a `POSIXct` object, not `character`. The line `substr(df$Date, 15,16) <- "00"` will break down and show *"Error: replacing substrings in a non-character object"*. You can use the data in my answer to reproduce the error.

Comment: You are right @Darren Tsai, I edit my answer to a POSIXct Date solution!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I accepted the other answer because it was first, but this answer was also helpful.